# migration from a heavy client project to a connected application to a server (currently under study DataSnap)

Tags: mysql, delphi, datasnap

Good morning, everyone,

As part of the migration from a heavy client project to a connected 
application to a server (currently under study DataSnap XE10.2) in order to transfer on an ad hoc basis and retrieve information from the server.

We would like to have some feedback on other available technologies, 
their durability and ease of adaptation.

Here is the profile of our application

The client connects to a remote server that can be hosted elsewhere.

There can be up to 300 clients connected at the same time over a period of 3 days.

these 300 customers can send on a variable hourly interval (1 to 2 hours and in a different way.

depending on the time of day (different countries).

These connections can transmit up to 5000 data so 300 = 1,500,000 over a period of one month.
For the moment we have chosen the DataSnap solution because it is already used on medical applications.

and especially for its ease of migration from the Delphi heavy client project to this type of architecture.

and also for his perenity with Delphi.

Our questions: what do you think?
                  What arguments and intermediate or other solutions do you propose? As far as RAD Server is concerned, this has a cost per license, but does it exit it examples of migration from a DataSnap application to RAD Server?
                  What are your experiences in these different areas? (concrete case in point)

On our side we will launch a simulation of 300 clients transmitting 5000 requests JSON REST to our DATASNAP server which will insert each of these queries into a database.

MySQL of 40GB, the insertion will return an acknowledgement of receipt and a written acknowledgement (simple boolean)

Thank you for your feedback, on our side we will publish the results of our tests

Comment: Is client application a web application? It runs in a web browser? Or is it a desktop application. Interested in mobile devices perhaps? Push notifications? Server-side session management? Queries are independent?

Answer (score 2):

There are [several solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3793112/458259), but I recommend our [Open Source mORMot framework](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#SOURCE).

Its SOA is based on `interface` type definitions, it is REST/JSON from the ground up, and was [reported to have very good performance and stability, especially in respect to DataSnap](https://robertocschneiders.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/datasnap-analysis-based-on-speed-stability-tests-part-2/comment-page-1/). It is Open Source and work with both Delphi and FPC (also [under Linux](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2018/02/07/mORMot-ORM-SOA-MVC-with-FPC)) - so could be considered as a safer solution for the middle/long term. DataSnap didn't evolve much since years, and I don't understand the RAD Server "black box" approach.

About migrating an existing database or system, check [this blog article](https://tamingthemormot.wordpress.com/2015/07/14/connecting-to-legacy-databases/) which shows some basic steps with mORMot.

You have other bricks available, like an ORM, a MVC layer for dynamic web site generation, logging, interface stubbing, high performance database layer, cross-platform clients, an exhaustive documentation and a lot of other features.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will study your solution that I have already been offered, are there any links with integration examples?

Comment: There is the blog article I quoted https://tamingthemormot.wordpress.com/2015/07/14/connecting-to-legacy-databases/ and also other material on our blog or documentation.

Comment: I wish mORMot was a little less tech-speak everywhere. For the first time understood after getting a context of DataSnap.